# iptables is occasionally logging MAC addresses. Why?

Tags: linux, iptables, logging, mac-address

I have logging enabled on specific iptables packet drops. The rules I'm using are IP/port related only and this is what I can easily see in the logs, however occasionally I do get MAC address information logged as well. Like:

"....OUT=eth1 IN= MAC=00:26:a9:7b:c9:30:00:17:0f:ac:6a:80:08:00"...

These mac-addresses related logs are sporadic.

**What I have noticed:**

- these dropped/mac-logged communication are always inbound
- the source mac-address logged is the one of my default-gateway (Service Provider), although the source IPs are different.
- the destination mac (obvious but just to confirm) is the one of my interface

**What I'm trying to understand:**

- what is the iptables logic when deciding to capture in the logs "MAC addresses + IP/port" instead of "IP/port" only.

Comment: Can you show what your `iptables` ruleset looks like?

Comment: You can use log prefix to pinpoint the specific iptables rule: see --log-prefix ""

Answer (score 3):

The MAC information is only logged for devices on your local network. It is actually a hex dump of the ethernet MAC header and consists of the source MAC address (00:26:a9:7b:c9:30), destination MAC address (00:17:0f:ac:6a:80) and ethernet frame type (08:00).

Answer (score 1):

The information has to be available. If not available, it won't be logged.

As IPv4 relies on ARP to resolve the MAC address of the destination, it's not known yet where *iptables* is concerned: such resolution happens later and never known in any of *iptables*' hooks, even once the destination IP address is known and even if such information usually remains cached in the neighbor ARP table.

So here's what happens as observed (using kernel 6.1) and inferred when involved interfaces are all Ethernet:

- PREROUTING/INPUT/FORWARD

  - The source and destination MAC addresses are always available in PREROUTING, INPUT or FORWARD.
  - for the FORWARD case the destination MAC address represents the local system's destination MAC address of the interface receiving the frame, not the future target system or gateway.
- OUTPUT

  - the source MAC address is not known: embedding the packet into a frame has not happened yet so such MAC address is not known.
  - the destination MAC address is not known either as explained
- POSTROUTING

  - if the packet is locally emitted (came through OUTPUT) then as in the OUTPUT case: no information is available
  - if the packet was routed (came through FORWARD): then the unchanged information from FORWARD is still available and logged even if "obsolete".

In short:

- PREROUTING, INPUT will always have the information
- FORWARD will always have the information from *before* routing
- OUTPUT will never have a MAC address in logs
- POSTROUTING will have it only if the packet was routed, and in this case, this will be the same information as logged in FORWARD.

Other cases when the information is not available is when it never exists:

- when the egress interface is not Ethernet (eg: lo, a layer 3 interface like WireGuard or OpenVPN in tun mode): then POSTROUTING won't display the "obsolete" MAC address it would have displayed otherwise when the packet was routed.
- when the ingress interface is not Ethernet: then no MAC address will appear in any hook.

---

I didn't consider how the behavior for bridged *frames* (at layer 2) traversing *iptables* (normally handling layer 3 *packets*) when the [`br_netfilter`](https://ebtables.netfilter.org/documentation/bridge-nf.html) module is loaded (typically by Docker) with the sysconf property `bridge-nf-call-iptables=1` can differ. These "packets" will also be logged with additional properties: `PHYSIN=` and `PHYSOUT=`.